# How to compute the following set of the matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $Z$ be the matrix

$$Z =
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2\\ 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$$

And the set $\text{Commu}(Z) = \{B ∈ M_{2\times2} | ZB = BZ\}$.

What is the set $\text{Commu}(Z)$? Isn't it just $\{ Z^{-1} , I\}$?

Thank you.

Comment: $2Z$ is in the set. As is $Z^2$. From there you can probably find infinitely many more on your own.

Comment: To see the set isn't just $\{ Z^{-1} , I\}$,  $(\alpha Z)^k\;k\in\mathbb{Z}$ is in the commutator where $\alpha\in \mathbb{F}$.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are infinitely many others.  Hint: eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

Use an equivalent form of commutativity:  J^{-1}ZJ J^{-1}BJ = J^{-1}BJ J^{-1}ZJ,
write the original matrix in Jordan canonical form, then you would get the possible B easily.